# How to display text on multiple lines?

Tags: php, radphp

I am using RadPhp to build a PHP application. I want to display several independent lines of text in an Edit control (using $this->edit->text property ) but it seems to be impossible. If I use \n it just displays it instead of braking this line in two.

---

PS: can anybody add 'RadPHP' as tag for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just replaced it with a simple label.
It works now.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience on RadPHP, but instead of `\n` character, try using `<br/>` to *break* your lines into two.

Answer (score 1):

For multiline text editing look at Memo component and Lines property

Answer (score 0):

Also don't know RadPHP as well but does it use `nl2br` or something similar to that and you forgot to insert it?